# jQuery dynamically populated rows

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

It must be a simple problem but i can't find out what exactly it is. If in a table i display one row that is static (Hard coded), and click on it, it shows the modal popup. But on the rows right below this row -which are populated dynamically through JQuery Ajax, with the same class attribute, it doesn't work. I don't know why.

Here is my table:

```
   <table class="tblContacts table toggle-circle" data-filter="#searchFilter" data-limit-navigation="5"
            data-filter-minimum="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th data-class="expand" data-toggle="true" data-sort-initial="true">
                        Name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Title
                    </th>
                    <th data-hide="phone">
                        Office
                    </th>
                    <th data-hide="phone">
                        Cell
                    </th>
                    <th data-hide="phone">
                        Email
                    </th>
                    <%--<th data-ignore="true" data-hide="all">--%>
                    <th data-ignore="true" data-hide="phone">
                        ID
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                                       <tr class="md-trigger pointer-hand" data-modal="modalContactPopup">
                        <td width="1" style="display: none !important">
                            <%#Eval("usersID")%>
                        </td>
                        <td data-sort-initial="true">
                            <%#Eval("usersFirstName")%>&nbsp;<%#Eval("usersLastName")%></td>
                        <td>
                            <%#Eval("usersTitle")%>
                        </td>
                        <td data-type="numeric">
                            <%#Eval("usersPhoneWork")%>
                        </td>
                        <td data-type="numeric">
                            <%#Eval("usersPhoneCell")%>
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">
                            <% //todo: Check if email exists first before formating like it is below... %>
                            <a href="mailto:<%#Eval("usersEmail1")%>" title="Click to email <%#Eval("usersEmail1")%>">
                                <i class="icon-envelope"></i>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

The  works fine, when i click on it , it shows me the Data modal using this code `data-modal="modalContactPopup"`

But if i populate my table with dynamically using this code:

```
   function PopulateData() {


        var footable = $('table').data('footable');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "contactsc2.aspx/getAllUsers",
            data: '{}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                var parsed = $.parseJSON(data.d);
                var newRow = "";
                $.each(parsed, function (i, jsondata) {
                    newRow += "<tr class='md-trigger pointer-hand' data-modal='modalContactPopup'><td>" + jsondata.usersFirstName + " " + jsondata.usersLastName + "</td><td>" + jsondata.usersTitle + "</td><td>" + jsondata.usersPhoneWork + "</td><td>" + jsondata.usersPhoneCell + "</td><td>" + jsondata.usersEmail1 + "</td><td>" + jsondata.usersID + "</td></tr>";

                });
                footable.appendRow(newRow);
            }
        });
    }
```

The popup doesn't open. Notice that I have included data-modal='modalContactPopup' when I am creating these rows dynamically. And it should work.
I have checked the page source and there is no difference between the Static row and the dynamic row on that source code, but even then, if i click on static, it is showing up the popup and not on other rows.

Can anyone think of a reason why?

Thanks

Comment: show js click function

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because you are adding click handlers to the specific elements when the page is loaded (elements with the selected class that are added in the future won't have a binded click handler): `$('.yourElementsClassName').click(function(){});`

To also handle the click events on elements that are added in the future use the `delegate` method, which selects all elements that match the selector, now or in the future, based on a specific set of root elements.

```
$('body').delegate('.yourElementsClassName', 'click', function(evt){});
```

Comment: i understand your point and believe THAT IS THE ISSUe. can you please tell me exactly where to add this delegate?

Comment: replace $('.yourElementsClassName').click(function(){ /*your code*/ }); with $('body').delegate('.yourElementsClassName', 'click', function(evt){ /*your code*/ });

Comment: in the populateData() function? Sorry, i am not very expert in JQuery. I must mention that data-modal is handling the click events, it is a MODAL POPUP jquery plugin that i am using. There is no specific ONCLICK method for the TR elements

Comment: could you please set up a jsfiddle so it's easier to help you?

Comment: i mean to say that on any element if i add data-modal='modalContactPopup', it opens the div called 'modalContactPopup' automatically through an external .js file that i am using

Comment: can you please see on Teamviewer please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.on() api](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to dynamically bind events or use [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) if you are using older version of jquery.

Comment: the pop up is showing by this attribute data-modal. This attribute is the part of Nifty Modal Popup that i am using. So there is no specific click event , that will show up the popup.

Comment: Then the event registration must have been handled by the framework you are using. Please look into the code of the framework and see how it handles the registration : using class ?? attribute??

Comment: there is something simple that i am missing. Like i said, when the document is loaded (With the static row that i have added), it populates other rows from DB. The static row can open the pop up, while dynamic rows don't. I am sure that i need to REDRAW or REINITIALIZE something here.